# running rails app on heroku, can't see static pages in /public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a couple static pages which when running locally work as localhost:3000/foo.html, but this doesn't work once uploaded to heroku.

I tried adding the following to the routes.rb file:

```
match '/foo', :to => redirect('/public/foo.html')
```

but that doesn't seem to work, it redirects me to foobar.com/public/foo.html, but still finds nothing there.

Comment: Do you have `config.serve_static_assets = true` in production environment configuration?

Comment: Somehow the static files never made it to the heroku side, my bad.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but some of my assets in /public weren't even being deployed to Heroku. The problem was that I'd forgotten about an exclude filter in my .slugignore file. It's only tangentially related to this, but my searches brought me here. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Per [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-static-assets-rails31#serve_static_assets), you will need to tell Rails to serve static assets itself with:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in your `config/environments/production.rb`

Comment: I accidentally down voted this answer, and it won't let me change the vote, but it is correct, thanks

Comment: Also make sure that you haven't included your public folder in the .gitignore. If you want to include only certain files, you can ignore the public folder and exclude the files you want to ignore.

Like:

/public/*
!/public/404.html

Comment: In recent versions of rails (eg Rails 6) this config is replaced with `config.public_file_server.enabled = true`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can add the `rails_12factor` gem to the production group:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

according to [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline#serve-assets). This will also redirect log to `stdout` as also required by Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

This baffled me for hours, but here's another potential solution. For some reason, I could generate documentation into `/public/docs`, but the documentation would not load, even immediately after I generated it. I would run a Heroku bash console, generate the documentation, exit, then re-run Heroku bash only to find that `/public` no longer contained my `docs` folder.

So, the only solution I found was to include the documentation in the Git repository. That was the only way that Heroku persisted `/public/docs` across deploys and bash instances.

I have no idea why this is... I opened a support ticket with Heroku and am awaiting a response.

Comment: could you please post response which you got from heroku support team ? that might help others.

Comment: This is because Heroku apps have an "ephemeral" file system: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem. This means that when a dyno is started, its file system is populated with a copy of the files that were present in the application slug when you deployed the app. When a dyno stops, all of its files are deleted. So if you want any files to be present on all of your dynos, they need to be generated before or during the build process, and included in the application slug.