# Pushing RoR app to Heroku, files in /public are missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

Let me start by saying I am using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.1.1

I've worked my way through the Treehouse basic RoR course; ending in a very basic version of Twitter. I have the application running just fine on my local install, but when I pushed it to Heroku it seems to be missing the files in the /public directory; namely the /assets css and javascript.

I've precompiled my assets as instructed, and verified that they area indeed showing up on my GitHub remote that is using the same branch. I was told that Heroku will not compile your assets for you.

All my routes and HTML is displaying just fine, but I cannot pull any of the files that live in the /public directory (404.html, 500.html, etc)

It feels to me like it is a permissions issue or something with the /public directory, but I haven't found a way to actually browse what files are on my Heroku instance. I've tried re-pushing several times while making small changes, and the css/js never seems to appear.

Comment: The question is answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440377/running-rails-app-on-heroku-cant-see-static-pages-in-public-folder
You should add config.serve_static_assets = true to your production configuration file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case that you have already set:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in your `config/environments/production.rb`

And still not working, you can actually see the logs from your heroku app using `heroku logs` or `heroku logs -n NUMBER_OF_DESIRED_LINES_HERE` in your terminal.