# Cannot render static sitemap.xml on Sinatra-Heroku website

Tags: ruby, xml, heroku, sinatra, sitemap

I've been tasked with adding a static sitemap.xml file to an existing heroku/sinatra site that I did not build. I dropped the file in 'public' but I get a 'document is empty' error in the browser: http://www.jeanpetitavocat.ca/sitemap.xml

There are plenty of guides on dynamic sitemaps but I just want to serve the static file, and I don't have a lot of experience with this platform.

Comment: It looks like this post may answer your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440377/running-rails-app-on-heroku-cant-see-static-pages-in-public-folder

Comment: @thohl that link is for Ruby on Rails, not Sinatra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be with your `sitemap.xml` file and not the serving of static files (`public/` is the right place for a default Sinatra app.

You need an XML declaration like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` at the beginning of your sitemap.

Comment: @Dave - Great to hear